Limit of solutions of Poisson equation with mixed boundary conditions on varying domain
Let $d=2,3$. Let $D$ be a simply connected, bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with smooth boundary. Assume that $\{x_d = 0\}$ is a tangent hyperplane of $D$. For $t>0$, let
$$D_t = D\cap \{x_d>t\}, \quad S_t = D\cap \{x_d=t\}, \quad R_t = \partial D  \cap \{x_d>t\}.$$
So, $R_t$ and $S_t$ is a "partition" of the boundary $\partial D_t$.
Let $u_t \in H^1(D)$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\Delta u_t = F \quad \mathrm{in}\ D_t, \\
& \frac{\partial u_t}{\partial N}= g \quad \mathrm{on} \ R_t, \\
& u_t =0 \quad \mathrm{on} \ S_t,
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation*}
with zero extension onto $D$, where $F$ is a data given in $D$, and $g$ is on $\partial D$.
My question is: Is there a limit of $u_t$ as $t\rightarrow 0$?
My thinking:

Intuitively, $u_t$ should goes to $u$, where $u$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\Delta u = F \quad \mathrm{in}\ D, \\
& \frac{\partial u}{\partial N}= g \quad \mathrm{on} \ \partial D.
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{equation*}
However, such $u$ is unique up to a constant. So, I guess that may we have $\| \nabla (u_t-u)\|_{L^2(D)} \rightarrow 0$.

My idea is first show $\|u_t\|_{H^1(D)}$ is uniformly bounded, then by compactness, I get a limit. However, I do not get a $H^1$ bound of $u_t$ which is uniformly in $t$. This is because, as $S_t$ vanishes, the constant of Poincare inequality blows up.


Could anyone gives me some ideas? I would appreciate for your kind help.

This is a pretty strange problem - why is it important to you?
